# Nginx WebDAV module ignoring CORS headers

Tags: nginx, cors, webdav, propfind

I am running WebDAV using Nginx. I have a JS app using it as a storage. The problem is that the WebDAV extension is removing headers that I added using "add_header" in my config.

```
server {
  # IP, Certificates, fullpath, autoindex ...
  dav_methods      PUT DELETE MKCOL COPY MOVE;
  dav_ext_methods  PROPFIND OPTIONS;
  dav_access       user:rw group:rw all:rw;

  location / {
    root /srv/http/content;

    # Preflighted requests
    if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
      add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" *;
      add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, OPTIONS, MOVE, DELETE, COPY, LOCK, UNLOCK, PROPFIND";
      add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, DNT, X-CustomHeader, Keep-Alive,User-Agent, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, Cache-Control, Content-Range, Range, Depth";
      return 200;
    }

    if ($request_method = (GET|POST|HEAD|DELETE|PROPFIND)) {
      add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" *;
      add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, OPTIONS, MOVE, DELETE, COPY, LOCK, UNLOCK, PROPFIND";
      add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept";
    }
  }
}
```

And when I open a WebDAV connection from my App it requests `OPTIONS` followed by `PROPFIND`. The request `OPTIONS` passes by having correct CORS headers but `PROPFIND` fails because no CORS headers were set.
Note the special case for `OPTIONS` in the config where I force Nginx to return `Http200`. Then the headers appear. But when letting the WebDAV to finish then all CORS headers disappear.

Did anyone circumvent this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue.

Try adding the `always` keyword to the `add_header` statements:

```
add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" * always;
add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, OPTIONS, MOVE, DELETE, COPY, LOCK, UNLOCK, PROPFIND" always;
add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, DNT, X-CustomHeader, Keep-Alive,User-Agent, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, Cache-Control, Content-Range, Range, Depth" always;
```

add_header docs:

> Syntax:   add_header name value [always];
>
> Adds the specified field to a response header provided that the
> response code equals 200, 201 (1.3.10), 204, 206, 301, 302, 303, 304,
> 307 (1.1.16, 1.0.13), or 308 (1.13.0). [...] If the always parameter
> is specified (1.7.5), the header field will be added regardless of the
> response code.

https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is a bug in nginx's webdav. I was able to get webdav (with CORS, authentication and SSL) running quickly using lighttpd. My example configuration

```
server.port         = 81
server.username     = "http"
server.groupname    = "http"
server.modules      = (
    "mod_webdav",
    "mod_auth",
    "mod_setenv", # before mod_status, very important!
    "mod_status",
    "mod_openssl"
    )
server.document-root= "/srv/http/content"
server.errorlog     = "/var/log/lighttpd/error.log"
ssl.engine          = "enable"
ssl.pemfile         = "/etc/ssl/webdav.key"
webdav.activate     = "enable"
auth.backend        = "htpasswd"
auth.backend.htpasswd.userfile = "/srv/http/passwd"
setenv.add-response-header     = (
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" => "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" => "GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, OPTIONS, MOVE, DELETE, COPY, LOCK, UNLOCK, PROPFIND",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" => "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, DNT, X-CustomHeader, Keep-Alive,User-Agent, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control, Content-Range, Range, Depth, Content-Length"
    )
mimetype.assign     = (
                ".html" => "text/html",
                ".txt" => "text/plain",
                ".css" => "text/css",
                ".js" => "application/x-javascript",
                ".jpg" => "image/jpeg",
                ".jpeg" => "image/jpeg",
                ".gif" => "image/gif",
                ".png" => "image/png",
                "" => "application/octet-stream"
            )
```